# Elastic search 5.3 - failed to find geo_point field

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-5, kibana-5

I am referring this [Geo Distance Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html) example given on elastic search documentation.

Version : 5.3

As per tutorial i performed this query to insert data in index

```
PUT /my_locations/location/1
{
    "pin" : {
        "location" : {
            "lat" : 40.12,
            "lon" : -71.34
        }
    }
}
```

Then I'm simply trying to apply Geo distance query which is also shown in documentation.

```
GET /my_locations/location/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
            "filter" : {
                "geo_distance" : {
                    "distance" : "200km",
                    "pin.location" : {
                        "lat" : 40,
                        "lon" : -70
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it is showing me this error. 
"failed to find geo_point field [pin.location]"
Other time it showed me this error 
"field [pin.location] is not a geo_point field".

Do i need to insert this record in a different way or am i missing some arguments in query?

Comment: can you post your index mapping? You have to specified the geo_point type on your filed in the mapping ( => https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html )

Comment: I looked into index pattern and it is showing me Data type for location is Number

Comment: {"gym":{"mappings":{"gyms":{"properties":{"location":{"type":"float"},"name":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"pin":{"properties":{"location":{"properties":{"lat":{"type":"float"},"lon":{"type":"float"}}}}}}}}}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @Pierre Mallet

I looked around with documentation and come to conclusion that i first need to create index with geo_point data type. I cannot apply data type on existed index. So my steps are like this

```
PUT gym
{
  "mappings": {
    "gyms": {
      "properties": {
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Insert record which contains location

```
PUT gym/gyms/1
{
  "location" : [ -71.34, 41.12 ]
}
```

Then look for index and it's data type

```
GET /gym/gyms/_mapping/
```

You will see that location field has geo_point data type. Then you can perform your query.

```
GET gym/gyms/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
            "filter" : {
              "geo_distance" : {
                    "distance" : "150km",
                    "location" : [ -70.34, 40.12 ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is working perfectly now.